# iterator pointing to single component of a struct within larger container in C++11, using std::function object

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

Say I have a vector of some struct type; I'm trying to iterate over all instances of a specific member within this struct. Because I want to be general in my approach I'd like to use a std::function<> object to specify which piece of information I'd like to access. I build the following template class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

template <typename SrcList, typename Tgt>
class Access
{
    typedef std::function<Tgt &(typename SrcList::value_type &)> func_type;
    typedef typename SrcList::iterator src_iterator;
    typedef Tgt value_type;

    SrcList &source;
    func_type f;

    public:
        Access(SrcList &source_, func_type const &f_):
            source(source_), f(f_) {}

        class iterator: 
            public src_iterator,
            public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, value_type>
        {
            Access const *obj;

            public:
                iterator(Access const *obj_, src_iterator i):
                    src_iterator(i), 
                    obj(obj_)
                {}

                value_type &operator*()
                {
                    return (obj->f)(src_iterator::operator*());
                }
        };

        value_type &operator[](size_t i)
        { return f(source[i]); }

        iterator begin()
        { return iterator(this, source.begin()); }

        iterator end()
        { return iterator(this, source.end()); }
};
```

next we define a struct S, and a main function to test the class

```
struct S
{
    double v[3];
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, S const &s)
{
    return out << s.v[0] << " " << s.v[1] << " " << s.v[2];
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    std::vector<S> Q(10);

    for (unsigned k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
    {
        Access<std::vector<S>, double> acc(Q,
            [k] (S &s) -> double&
        {
            return s.v[k];
        });

        std::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), acc.begin(),
            [k] (int i)
        {
            return pow(i, k+1);
        });

        for (auto x : Q)
            std::cout << x.v[k] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "--- end of part " << k << " ---\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (auto x : Q)
        std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

this program should print the numbers 0..10, their squares and their cubes. The method seems to work, however I get a memory dump, right after printing "--- end of part 1 ---", saying: "double free or corruption". I've ran the code through gdb, and it seems somethings going wrong in the memory management of the std::function<> member in Access<>, but I can't figure what precisely breaks this code. I've build a similar construct with read-only access, and it works flawlessly.

What am I doing wrong here?

(using g++-4.7.2)

Cheers, Johan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that vector `A` contains 11 entries, while vector `Q` contains only 10. `std::transform<>` expects the target range to be at least as big as the source range.

A simple fix would be to change the definition of `Q` as follows:

```
std::vector<S> Q(A.size());
```

Comment: @Johannes: no worries, we've all been there